# Is it possible to change a radiobuttonlist so that it put's a div around each input/label?

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

So that rather than `<input><label>` I can get `<div><input><label></div>` for each of the items in my datasource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want that level of control, you'll need to use something like a [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx).

Comment: Can I group radiobuttons in it or will it screw them up like a repeater?

Comment: You'd have to add some javacript to replicate the same functionality as the radio buttons list. Bit of a hassle, but you'd at least have full control.